# How to detect next task in list, depending on sequential order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given is an array with n projects. Each project can contain n unsorted tasks. Sample:

```
projects = [
    {"name" : "Sampleproject 1", "tasks" : 
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 1", "status" : "Done"},
        {"order" : 3, "description" : "Do something 3", "status" : "Open"},
        {"order" : 2, "description" : "Do something 2", "status" : "Open"}
    },
    {"name" : "Sampleproject 2", "tasks" : 
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 1", "status" : "Done"},
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 3", "status" : "Open"},
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 2", "status" : "Open"},
        {"order" : 2, "description" : "Do something 4", "status" : "Open"}
    }
]
```

I have to add an *active* key for each task, if it can be processed by the user.

Tasks can be processed parallel and sequential, represented by the order number. This means: All tasks with ordernumber 1 have to be done before a tasks with order 2 can be processed, all taks with ordernumber 2 have to be done before 3 can be processed, and so on ...

Required output:

```
projects = [
    {"name" : "Sampleproject 1", "tasks" : 
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 1", "status" : "Done", "active" : false},
        {"order" : 3, "description" : "Do something 3", "status" : "Open", "active" : false},
        {"order" : 2, "description" : "Do something 2", "status" : "Open", "active" : true}
    },
    {"name" : "Sampleproject 2", "tasks" : 
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 1", "status" : "Done", "active" : false},
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 3", "status" : "Open", "active" : true},
        {"order" : 1, "description" : "Do something 2", "status" : "Open", "active" : true},
        {"order" : 2, "description" : "Do something 4", "status" : "Open", "active" : false}
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be a task for each order?  For example a project with two tasks of order 1 and 3 is disallowed

Comment: @Simon Yes, for each ordernumber exists at least one tasks. But the tasks are unsorted, so it´s not guaranteed that the next task has the next higher ordernumber (Like "Sampleproject 1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most efficient solution, but you could sort the tasks by `order`, then set the most recent priority order/s with `Open` status to `active` and the rest to `false`. The time complexity is probably `O(P * TLog(T) + T)`, which can be simplified to just `O(P * TLog(T))`, where `P` is the number of projects, and `T` is the number of tasks per project. Sorting is `NLog(N)`, so thats where the `TLog(T)` comes from.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from json import dumps

projects = [
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 1",
        "tasks": [
            {"order": 1, "description": "Do something 1", "status": "Done"},
            {"order": 3, "description": "Do something 3", "status": "Open"},
            {"order": 2, "description": "Do something 2", "status": "Open"},
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 2",
        "tasks": [
            {"order": 1, "description": "Do something 1", "status": "Done"},
            {"order": 1, "description": "Do something 3", "status": "Open"},
            {"order": 1, "description": "Do something 2", "status": "Open"},
            {"order": 2, "description": "Do something 4", "status": "Open"},
        ],
    },
]

for project in projects:
    sorted_tasks = sorted(project["tasks"], key=itemgetter("order"))

    priority_order = None
    for task in sorted_tasks:
        if task["status"] == "Open" and (priority_order is None or task["order"] == priority_order):
            task["active"] = True
            priority_order = task["order"]
        else:
            task["active"] = False

print(dumps(projects, indent=4))
```

Output as JSON(for easier viewing of the result):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 1",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 1",
                "status": "Done",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "order": 3,
                "description": "Do something 3",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "description": "Do something 2",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Sampleproject 2",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 1",
                "status": "Done",
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 3",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "order": 1,
                "description": "Do something 2",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "description": "Do something 4",
                "status": "Open",
                "active": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

We go through the list of tasks, finding the minimum order of an open task.  Then we go through the list again and set those with that order to `active: true` and the rest to `active: false`

```py
def add_active(project):
    min_open = float("inf")
    for t in project["tasks"]:
        if t["status"] == "Open":
            min_open = min(min_open, t["order"])
    for t in project["tasks"]:
        if t["status"] == "Open" and t["order"] == min_open:
            t["active"] = "true"
        else:
            t["active"] = "false"

for p in projects:
    add_active(p)

print(projects)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a `heap` to keep track of the lowest order. On each heappop, you would iterate through all the tasks and just need to check if the order is the one to be serviced and if it's open. This would look like this:

```
In [25]: from heapq import heappush, heappop                                                   

In [26]: heap = []                                                                             

In [27]: order_tracking = set()                                                                

In [28]: for project in projects: 
    ...:     for task in project['tasks']: 
    ...:         order_num = task['order'] 
    ...:         if order_num not in order_tracking: 
    ...:             heappush(heap, order_num) 
    ...:             order_tracking.add(order_num) 
    ...:              
    ...:                                                                                       

In [29]: heap                                                                                  
Out[29]: [1, 3, 2]
```

This builds up the min heap for order numbers. Now we just need to service each one:

```
In [31]: next_to_service = heappop(heap)      
In [32]: for project in projects: 
...:     for task in project['tasks']: 
...:         order_num = task['order'] 
...:         # If the order number matches 
...:         if order_num == next_to_service: 
...:             if task['status'] == 'Open': 
...:                 task['active'] = 'true' 
...:             else: 
...:                 task['active'] = 'false' 
...:         # Otherwise we can set it False 
...:         else: 
...:             task['active'] = 'false' 
...:
```

Now you would get `projects` to look like:

```
In [36]: pprint.pprint(projects)                                                                                             
[{'name': 'Sampleproject 1',
  'tasks': [{'active': 'false',
             'description': 'Do something 1',
             'order': 1,
             'status': 'Done'},
            {'active': 'false',
             'description': 'Do something 3',
             'order': 3,
             'status': 'Open'},
            {'active': 'false',
             'description': 'Do something 2',
             'order': 2,
             'status': 'Open'}]},
 {'name': 'Sampleproject 2',
  'tasks': [{'active': 'false',
             'description': 'Do something 1',
             'order': 1,
             'status': 'Done'},
            {'active': 'true',
             'description': 'Do something 3',
             'order': 1,
             'status': 'Open'},
            {'active': 'true',
             'description': 'Do something 2',
             'order': 1,
             'status': 'Open'},
            {'active': 'false',
             'description': 'Do something 4',
             'order': 2,
             'status': 'Open'}]}]
```

And then because it's a heap:

```
In [37]: heap                                                                                                                
Out[37]: [2, 3]
```

You have the next one to service at the beginning again. And you can repeat that same process of `heappop` until the heap is empty and all orders have been serviced.